# ST L4 series datasheet specifications and 1 wire

Tags: stm32, datasheet, 1-wire

When you open [STM32L476](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c5/ed/2f/60/aa/79/42/0b/DM00108832.pdf/files/DM00108832.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00108832.pdf) specification on the The DFSDM peripheral supports (42/232) it says that "Manchester coded 1 wire interface support". Does this means it supports 1-Wire bus like for [DS18S20](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18S20.pdf) or it can support some sort of communication on 1 wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the DFSDM peripheral cannot be used to interface 1-wire (dallas) bus. It has nothing to do with it. It is used to interface sigma-delta modulators only, and the protocol is totally different.

To interface 1-wire peripherals with ST MCUs, you have to implement it in software, but there are libraries that does it already. With a quick search on the internet, I found [this](http://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/05/library-12-onewire-library-for-stm43f4xx/) (I guess it does not need many changes to be adapted for STM32L4). There are certainly many others.